# What is a good book to learn about the fall of Geocentrism?

Tags: geocentrism

I want to read about the paradigm shifting from Geocentrism to Heliocentrism. I am looking for a book which explains all of the details in a way that someone without so much astronomical knowledge can understand. Are there any good recommendations?

EDIT: I am more interested in the physics than the politics of the issue…

Comment: Which details? Do you just want to know about the astronomy & physics, or do you also want to know about the political, religious, and philosophical aspects?

Comment: There is a dedicated site [hsm.se] which is much better at the history aspects of such a question.

Comment: @PM2Ring The astronomy and physics is my main interest, and the political aspect is a bonus but not really necessary…

Comment: Have you tried searching goodreads?  I found *A More Perfect Heaven: How Copernicus Revolutionized the Cosmos*  and *The Book Nobody Read: Chasing the Revolutions of Nicolaus Copernicus*  and  *Heaven on Earth: How Copernicus, Brahe, Kepler, and Galileo Discovered the Modern World*  any of which might be of interest.

Comment: You might try some of the references from the Wikipedia entry for the history of geodesy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_geodesy .  Though from my own research, it appears the most important stuff is lost to time.